# Nuxt build can't resolve empty tailwind css variables (ring)

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, production-environment

I am building Vue application with Nuxt and tailwindcss and I am dealing with a problem which is only occurring on production (or with built app) not while testing on development environment. I am suspecting `nuxt build`  is doing some magic with my css because I am not using any CSS plugins like cssnano or postcss.

I am using **tailwind class "ring-2"** which is defined as

```
box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(2px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
```

While I see the ring style applied on development, it disappears on production.
When I inspect the element in chrome i see that **--tw-ring-inset looks like not defined**.
In the code I see that this variable is defined like this

```
 --tw-ring-inset: var(--tw-empty,/*!*/ /*!*/);
```

Which is probably resolved to **--tw-ring-inset: ;** which might be taken as wrong syntax and hence undefined.

I see people having problems with this like here https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1404 or here https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/1350 but I am not using any of this libraries.

Have anybody encountered same problem or have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What is your tailwind version and setup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly the problem is, but I removed 'extractCSS: true' property from Build property inside nuxt.config.js. And it works well for me.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz1XC.png)